# How to write a loop to log a message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, console

I have a assignment for a school project. The task is Write a for loop to log the message “I am love making pizza pies!” 10 times to the console.

Here's my code: *I am using google Chrome as my browser*

```js
var pizza = '10'
for (var pizza = 0; < I.love.making.pizza; < pizza++) {
  if (I.love.making.pizza;) {
    pizza++;
  }
}
console.log('I Love Making Pizza');
```

Comment: Execute the code above, and find information in [Google](https://www.google.com) to learn how a `for-loop` works.

Comment: What should this be??? This is not even pseudocode.

Answer (score -1):

Step by step:

```
for (var i =0; i<10; i++){ // our loop.
   console.log('I Love Making Pizza'); //our loop body
}
```

i is the variable we are iterating over. It starts at 0 (hence the var i =0 part). And after doing the loop body (the part between curly brackets) it gets increased by 1 (the i++ part which just means i=i+1). We do this as long as i is smaller than 10 (so until i is 9). Since from 0 to 9 there are 10 numbers we execute out loop body 10 times

Alternatively:

```
for (var i =1; i<=11; i=i+1){ // our loop.
   console.log('I Love Making Pizza'); //our loop body
}
```

Now we go from 1 to 10 including 10 (hence the <=)

Comment: Do you really think you will help with this??

Answer (score -1):

```
for(pizza = 0;pizza <= 10;pizza++){
  console.log("I am love making pizza pies!");
}
```

The code above should do the trick.